# Get unique values in a dictionary of sets

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary where the values are of type set, as follows:

```
d = collections.defaultdict(set)
```

I wish to create a single set which contains each value stored in the dictionary's sets, for example,

```
d[1] = {'foo', 'bar'}
d[2] = {'bar', 'baz'}
```

should give:

```
{'foo', 'bar', 'baz'}
```

I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
set([v for v in st for st in d.values()])
```

Instead I get: `NameError: name 'st' is not defined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) is the wrong way round, you need:

```
set([v for st in d.values() for v in st])
```

Also note that you could use a [generator expression](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) instead which is more memory-friendly:

```
set(v for st in d.values() for v in st)
```

This is then equivalent to:

```
s = set()
for st in d.values():
    for v in st:
        s.add(v)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is just the union of the values

```
set.union(*d.values())
```

eg:

```
>>> d = collections.defaultdict(set)
>>> d[1] = {'foo', 'bar'}
>>> d[2] = {'bar', 'baz'}
>>> set.union(*d.values())
{'baz', 'foo', 'bar'}
```

If `d` is a very big dict, for bonus points you may wish to avoid unpacking(*) the values.

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x.union(y), d.values(), set())
{'baz', 'foo', 'bar'}
```

Comment: The reduce operation is at the cost of creating multiple sets. The unpacking may be efficient in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the reduce operation suggested by @gnibbler. If you want to still use `for`, then you can avoid too many calls to `union`, by eliminating one nested for.

```
s = set()
for st in d.values():
    s = s.union(st)
```

But, this loop is at the cost of creating a new set every time. Therefore, it depends upon the content of your dict.